# Sort Hash Key and Value simultaneously Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have a hash that I want to sort the keys numerically in ascending order and
its values in ascending alphabetically manner.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils;
use Tie::IxHash;    

my %KEY_VALUE;
#tie %KEY_VALUE,'Tie::IxHash';


my %KEY_VALUE= (
    0 => [ 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A' ,'D'],
    5 => [ 'D', 'F', 'E', ],
    2 => [ 'Z', 'X', 'Y' ],
    4 => [ 'E', 'R', 'M' ],
    3 => [ 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A' ],
    1 => [ 'C', 'C', 'F', 'E' ],
    );

#while (my ($k, $av) = each %KEY_VALUE) 
#{
#  print "$k @$av\n ";
#}

#Sort the key numerically   
foreach my $key (sort keys %KEY_VALUE)
{
 print "$key\n";
}

#To sort the value alphabetically
foreach my $key (sort {$KEY_VALUE{$a} cmp $KEY_VALUE{$b}} keys %KEY_VALUE){
       print "$key: $KEY_VALUE{$key}\n";
}
```

The wanted input is like this, and I want to print out the sorted keys and values.

```
%KEY_VALUE= (
    0 => [ 'A','A','B','C','D'],
    1 => [ 'C','C','E','F' ],
    2 => [ 'X','Y','Z' ],
    3 => [ 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B' ],
    4 => [ 'E','M','R' ],
    5 => [ 'D','E','F', ],
);
```

Additional problem, how to print the key and the scalar value of the first different value

Wanted Output:

```
KEY= 0  VALUE:0 2 3 4   #The scalar value of first A B C D, start with 0
KEY= 1  VALUE:0 2 3     #The scalar value of first C E F
KEY= 2  VALUE:0 1 2     #The scalar value of first X Y Z
KEY= 3  VALUE:0 2       #The scalar value of first A B
KEY= 4  VALUE:0 1 2     #The scalar value of first E M R
KEY= 5  VALUE:0 1 2     #The scalar value of first D E F
```

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: @Schwern, okey. Thank you for your positive comment!

Answer (score 3):

Hash keys have no defined order. Generally you sort the keys as you're iterating through the hash.

The values can be sorted as you iterate through the hash.

```
# Iterate through the keys in numeric order.
for my $key (sort {$a <=> $b } keys %hash) {
    # Get the value
    my $val = $hash{$key};

    # Sort it in place
    @$val = sort { $a cmp $b } @$val;

    # Display it
    say "$key -> @$val";
}
```

Note that by default `sort` sorts in ASCII order as strings. That means `sort keys %KEY_VALUE` is not sorting as numbers but as strings. `sort(2,3,10)` is `(10,2,3)`. `"10"` is less than `"2"` like `"ah"` is less than `"b"`. Be sure to use `sort { $a <=> $b }` for numeric sorting and `sort { $a cmp $b }` for strings.

You could use a different data structure such as [Tie::Ixhash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) though tying has a significant performance penalty. Generally it's better to sort in place unless your hash gets very large.

Comment: thank you for this knowledge! By the way, for my additional question/problem, is it doable using hash?

Comment: @DanialHaris The important thing to realize is that part has nothing to do with the hash. It's a thing you want to do to arrays. They just happen to be values in a hash. Consider how you'd accomplish turning the array `['A','A','B','C','D']` into `0, 2, 3, 4`. Code that up. Then put that code into the loop to work on each value of the hash. Or better, put that code into a function and use that function on each value in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort a hash, you can at best print it sorted (or keep the sorted keys in another array). Finding the position of the first value can be done with `first_index`; we remove duplicates with `uniq`.

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %KEY_VALUE) {
  my @value = @{$KEY_VALUE{$key}};
  my @indices = map { my $e = $_; first_index { $_ eq $e } @value } (uniq (sort @value));
  print "$key: " . (join ', ', @indices) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I see, that is why, the value of the hash can't be update even though I have sorted it. Thank you for this knowledge.